# Obtain a text list of OUs from a computer that isn't on a domain without AD module using powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to write powershell code that can retrieve a list of OUs from a given domain for further processing. I just want a purely text list (for various reasons.) I can't install the AD module on these machines.

```
$tld = "lan"
$domain = "contoso"
$adLogin = "Administrator"

$mainOU = "Workstations"
$dnSuffix = "OU=$mainOU,DC=$domain,DC=$tld"
$computerPrefix = ""
$computerSuffix = ""
$DomainDN = "LDAP://$domain.$tld"

$adDomain = "$domain" + "." + "$tld"
$adAuthName = "$adDomain\$adLogin"
$Credential = Get-Credential -Credential $adAuthName

# There's probably a better way to do this, but the adsi searcher documentation is hard to sift through, and these machines can't install the AD module.
$remoteObject = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry -ArgumentList $DomainDN,$($Credential.UserName),$($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().password)
$adObj = ([ADSISearcher]"ObjectClass=OrganizationalUnit")
$adObj.SearchRoot = $remoteObject
$adObj.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange("CanonicalName")
$ouList = $adObj.findall().Properties.canonicalname | Select-String $mainOU | Out-String
$ouList = $ouList.ToString()
$removeText = "$domain" + "." + "$tld" + "/" + "$mainOU"
$ouList = $ouList -replace $removeText
$ouList = $ouList -replace "/"
$ouList = $ouList.Trim()
$ouList = $ouList.Split("`n")
echo $ouList
```

Running it on a computer inside of the target domain yields this: (these are bogus OUs for a lab simulation.)

```
    chips
    vinegar
    salsa
```

But running it on a computer outside of the domain yields nothing. Powershell doesn't seem to provide any tools for troubleshooting why. And yes, I already verified that I can resolve contoso.lan from that machine. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I copy pasted this onto my home computer (non-domain joined) which has a VPN connection into an AD network. Once I changed `$tld`, `$domain`, `$adLogin`, and `$mainOU` to values that correspond to that domain, it worked perfectly (so great job). I can't figure out a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Could be something odd about my setup. I'm really not sure, but I did find a more elegant solution to my earlier problem that also works. I'm going to post it as an answer.

Comment: You may met a security limit. I exists policies that are used to forbid authentication from computer outside the domain.

Comment: I tested it in a lab environment that is just a fresh install of Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter edition, only promoted to a domain named contoso.lan. Not sure why it wouldn't work. The code I showed is exactly what I used (domain name, tld, and all.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more elegant solution to my own problem that works:

```
$domain = "contoso"
$tld = "lan"
$adLogin = "Administrator"

$mainOU = "Workstations"
$dnSuffix = "OU=$mainOU,DC=$domain,DC=$tld"

$adDomain = "$domain" + "." + "$tld"
$adAuthName = "$adDomain\$adLogin"
$adCredentials = Get-Credential -Credential $adAuthName
$ldapRootPath = "LDAP://" + "$domain" + "." + "$tld"
$ldapWorkstationPath = "LDAP://" + "$domain" + "." + "$tld" + "/OU=" + "$mainOU" + ",DC=" + "$domain" + ",DC=" + "$tld"

$remoteObject = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("$ldapWorkstationPath",$($adCredentials.UserName),$($adCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().password)) -ErrorAction 'Stop' -ErrorVariable ErrProcessNewObjectCred
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $remoteObject
$objSearcher.Filter = ("(objectCategory=OrganizationalUnit)")
foreach ($item in "name") {$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($item) | Out-Null }
$searchResult = $objSearcher.FindAll()
$ouList = foreach ($result in $searchResult) {$objOrganizationalUnit = $result.Properties; $objOrganizationalUnit.name}
```

Although the search body is different, I think the reason the code posted in my question doesn't work is because I had an incomplete LDAP path. Should be LDAP://contoso.lan/OU=Workstaions,DC=contoso,DC=lan (The examples I found only showed that you need LDAP://dc=contoso,dc=lan, which is wrong, and powershell doesn't bother telling you that it's wrong and just pretends nothing happened.)

I based it off of a code example I found somewhere, but now I can't find it again, otherwise I'd give the original author credit. (Ironically it was part of a discussion thread where the author threw it out in favor of doing it with an AD module - an option I don't have.)

I see why they use the AD module as this process seems very convoluted, and if I'm not mistaken is .net based? (I honestly don't know the difference between what is .net and what isn't; I just follow the examples and adapt it to my needs as I'm not skilled enough to be an actual software developer, lol.)